# Point the max value in stat_summary mean line with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this kind of data

```
                 Time      Value  Type
1 2018-04-23 00:00:00 0.00000000 FALSE
2 2018-04-23 00:10:00 0.08971613 FALSE
3 2018-04-23 00:20:00 0.02626635 FALSE
4 2018-04-23 00:30:00 0.40684988 FALSE
5 2018-04-23 00:40:00 0.29159049 FALSE
6 2018-04-23 00:50:00 0.54625109 FALSE
```

Then this code

```
graph <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Time, y = Value, colour = Type, group = Type)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.75, show.legend = FALSE) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", size = 0.5, aes(colour = Type), show.legend = FALSE)

ggsave("test.png", width = 6.4, height = 4, dpi = 200, units = "in")
```

output this image.

[image]

But I couldn't find a way to emphasize the maximum value in each series by `summary_stat`. I suspected `fun.ymax` was the key but didn't succeeded.

Could anyone suggest an idea please?

Comment: Try to add `stat_summary(fun.y = max, colour = "orange", geom = "point", size = 5)`. This will show the max value depended on each x value. Thus, subset the data first like `stat_summary(data=data[which.max(data$value),], fun.y = max, colour = "orange", geom = "point", size = 5)`

Comment: The code points out the maximum value of the points in the plot, not the maximum value of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stat_summary_bin` and persuade it that you have only one bin. `geom_rug` works with this.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) + 
geom_point() + 
stat_summary_bin(fun.y  = max, geom = "rug", breaks = range(mtcars$cyl), colour = "red", sides = "l")
```

If you want a line all the way across, you need `geom_hline` which does not play nicely with `stat_summary` so you would need to pre-calculate the maximum values with code like

```
ggplot(...) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = max), data %>% group_by(Type) %>% summarise(max = max(Value))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'd like to point out **the maximum value of the maximum-value line**. Is it possible?

Comment: `stat_summary_bin` does something close to what I needed, but it still shows the maximum value of the points.